# Populate table view from Struct

Tags: swift, uitableview, struct

I have a Struct such as:

```
struct Test {
            var name: String?
            var value: Float?
            var isfavorite:String? 


    init(name: String, value: Float, favorite: String){

        self.name = name
        self.value = rawRate
        self.favorite = favorite
    }
}
```

And a String in wich I stored a string according to the Test Struct

```
var TestInformation = [String:Test]()
```

When I want to populate a tableview based on the content of TestInformation I get the following error:

```
[String : Test]' does not have a member named 'name'
```

Here is the line I use to populate the tableview:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            cell.testlabel?.text =  TestInformation[indexPath.row].name
}
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, maybe someone point me to right direction.

Thank you :)

Edit :

I add information to testInformation by doing the following:

```
let testInformation =  [
    Test(name: "Foo1", value: 1.32, isfavorite: "favorite"),
    Test(name: "Foo2", value: 1.27, isfavorite: "favorite")]
```

Comment: where do you add stuff to TestInformation? TestInformation is a dictionary that maps a String to a Test structs, yet you are trying to access it using indexPath.row. Did you perhaps mean for it to be an array of Test structs?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did try to change `TestInformation = [String:Test]` to `TestInformation = [Array:Test]` but I get an error `Type 'Array' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'`

Comment: `var TestInformation = [Test]()` creates an array of Test structs. What you were trying to do was create a Dictionary that maps an Array to a Test, which is impossible. the [ : ] thing creates a dictionary.